# How to exclude a certain day of the week in cron, and only on a certain week

Tags: cron

Basically, I want to run a job on the first, second, fourth, and if available, fifth friday of each month. Or in other words, all Fridays except for the third Friday.

Edit: this is more java oriented, there is no access to a bash environment.

Comment: Can you describe what type of system you are running on?  If you have access to cron, most likely you have access to a shell and you can write an sh script to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually check for it in a script:

```
date "%u"
```

gives you the day of the week (same as the dow field in cron)

To get the week number of each month, you have to do something funky.

```
date +"%V"
```

gives you the week of the month, so you'd have to look at

```
x=`date +"%V"`
y=`date +"%V" -d $(date +"%Y%m01")`
week_of_month=$((x-y))
```

week_of_month starts at 0 so you would want to check if it is not two.

So in your cron, you would run the script every friday, and put a check at the top of the script:

```
x=`date +"%V"`
y=`date +"%V" -d $(date +"%Y%m01")`
week_of_month=$((x-y))
if [ "$week_of_month" == "2" ]; then
    echo "Will not run second friday of the month"
    exit;
fi
```